# Adding CSS classes using classList in Javascript function but styles are conflicting as latest class is not taking precedence

Tags: javascript, html, css, handlebars.js

My function counts the visible cards on screen and if all are shown, then the `arrow-up` class is added to my icon, if some are still hidden from the user, the `arrow-down` icon is added.

```
const showMoreIcon = document.querySelector('.cta-icon');

function myFunction(){
   const btnIcon = cardsOnShow >= cards.length ? 'arrow-up' : 'arrow-down';
   showMoreIcon.classList.add(btnIcon);
}
```

```
<span class="medium-icon"></span>
```

This works and I can see in the DOM the correct class being added to the `span` when I expect it to, however, because the `arrow-down` class is added first (user must expand content several times before all visible cards are shown) - then despite the `arrow-up` class being added, it's not overwriting the `arrow-down`.

How can I ensure that when `arrow-up` is added, `arrow-down` is removed and vice versa? I've previously used `toggle` for simple open/close icons but this will not work due to the fact it could be expanded multiple times before being closed.

Comment: The order in which classes are added/listed on elements has no effect. It's down to [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of factors which are taken into account by [the cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-6/), which is the set of rules used to determine which rule "wins" when two conflicting rules are applied to the same element.

The order in which classes are defined **on the HTML element** is not one of those factors.

`<div class="foo bar">` and `<div class="bar foo">` are identical as far as the cascade is concerned.

---

**Remove** the class which shouldn't apply.

```
if (cardsOnShow >= cards.length) {
    showMoreIcon.classList.add("arrow-up");
    showMoreIcon.classList.remove("arrow-down");
} else {
    showMoreIcon.classList.add("arrow-down");
    showMoreIcon.classList.remove("arrow-up");
}
```

Alternatively write your CSS in a way that only cares about a single class to change the direction:

```
.arrow {
    /* arrow up CSS */
}
.arrow.invert {
    /* override the up rule and replace with the down rule
}
```

and then

```
if (cardsOnShow >= cards.length) {
    showMoreIcon.classList.remove("invert");
} else {
    showMoreIcon.classList.add("invert");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend removing the class you no longer want:

```js
function myFunction(){
   if (cardsOnShow >= cards.length) {
      showMoreIcon.classList.add('arrow-up')
      showMoreIcon.classList.remove('arrow-down')
   } else {
      showMoreIcon.classList.remove('arrow-up')
      showMoreIcon.classList.add('arrow-down')
   }
}
```